# Converting horizontal records to flat records using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to convert the following format of records:

[image]

To a flat record, like the below, using VBA.

[image]

Please could you give me some pointers on how to begin this using VBA?

Comment: If you are able to try PQ (powerquery) I'm prety sure it's just a few clicks :). How set are you on using VBA?

Comment: Does the amount of blocks to be converted to flat form is constant (as in sample data - 3)?

Comment: *how to begin this using VBA?* Get header data into array, extract dates and define blocks amount. Get all data into array, copy it into another array with proper reordering and add dates, store it to another worksheet.

Comment: Change your search parameters.  Google "VBA normalize data".